# How to add java listeners to java component in Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab

To add java component to Matlab GUI I use undocumented function `javacomponent`:

```
[handles.myWidget, handles.hMyWidget] = javacomponent('com.mycompany.MyClass', [90,10,460,400], gcf);
```

Simultaneously, to add event listener callback, I need to invoke addlistener:

```
handles.myWidgetListeners = addlistener( myhandle, 'MouseClickedCallback', @mouseClicked_Callback);
```

Neither of handles returned by `javacomponent` fits to `addlistener`, so I need to create one more handle with:

```
myhandle = handle(handles.myWidget, 'CallbackProperties');
```

So, is this true, that I need to keep **FOUR** handles for **ONE** component in order to fully operate with it?

Isn't it possible to shorten this code?

Answer (score 0):

While all of the steps that you have outlined are a requirement for assigning a MATLAB callback for Java swing events created via `javacomponents`, you don't need to necessarily store all four handles that are created.

```
[jwidget, hwidget] = javacomponent('myclass', [0 0 100 100], gcf);
hwidget = handle(hwidget, 'CallbackProperties');
```

You don't need to maintain *both* `hwidget` and the result of `handle(hwidget, 'CallbackProperties')` as they are functionally equivalent.

The other option is to simply not use `javacomponent` when creating your java object and then get the "CallbackProperties" handle from that.

```
jwidget = com.mycompany.myclass();
hwidget = handle(jwidget, 'CallbackProperties');
```

Also, as far as the listener goes, you don't necessarily need to explicitly store this as a variable and track it around your GUI. You could instead simply store it within the widget itself and then if you ever need to disable it you can fetch it the same way.

```
listener = addlistener(hwdiget, 'MouseClickedCallback', @mouseclick);
set(hwidget, 'UserData', listener);
```